# Custom list to array of arrays

Tags: c#, json

I need your help to solve this in the most efficient way.

I have a List of custom object.

```
var customList = new List<Custom>();
public class Custom
{
  public DateTime Date {get;set;}
  public double Value {get;set;}
}
```

I want to convert my customList to an array of arrays like this with the dates in UTC format:

```
[
  [Date.UTC(1970, 9, 21), 0],
  [Date.UTC(1971, 3, 11), 5.4],
  [Date.UTC(1971, 5, 20), 11.2],
  [Date.UTC(1973, 11, 09), 3.0]
]
```

Comment: @diiN_ "the most efficient way" is having someone else code it for you. Didn't you read that part? :-p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using Linq:

```
var arr = customList.Select(x => new object[] { x.Date, x.Value }).ToArray();
```